# Environement.NewLine só funciona na primeira linha

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Boa tarde. To tentando gerar um arquivo de texto e ele só funciona na primeira linha. A partir da segunda linha, ele dá um espaço que não to conseguindo resolver.

```
foreach (DadosSQL dados in listaDados){
            sb.AppendFormat("{0, -18}{1, -10}{2, -37}{3, -15}{4, -25}{5, -10}{6, -15}{7, -18}{8, -20}{9, -11}{10, -22}{11, -19}{12, -21}{13, -21}",
                dados.REFERENCIA_ALIADO.ToString(), dados.COD_SKU_USUARIO, dados.NOM_SKU, dados.DESCRICAO, dados.NOM_MARCA_SORTIMENTO, dados.QTD_DISPONIVEL, dados.TIENDA, dados.PRECO, dados.PRECO_COM_DESCONTO,
            dados.DESCONTO, dados.INICIO_DESCONTO, dados.FIM_DESCONTO,  dados.CATEGORIA_1, Environment.NewLine);}   
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\\Teste\\teste.txt", sb.ToString());
```

A saída tá na imagem em anexo:

[image: ErroNewLine]

Answer (score 1):

O último formato está adicionando espaços depois do `NewLine`.

Altere para isso:

```
foreach (DadosSQL dados in listaDados)
{
  sb.AppendFormat("{0, -18}{1, -10}{2, -37}{3, -15}{4, -25}{5, -10}{6, -15}{7, -18}{8, -20}{9, -11}{10, -22}{11, -19}{12, -21}",dados.REFERENCIA_ALIADO.ToString(), dados.COD_SKU_USUARIO, dados.NOM_SKU, dados.DESCRICAO, dados.NOM_MARCA_SORTIMENTO, dados.QTD_DISPONIVEL, dados.TIENDA, dados.PRECO, dados.PRECO_COM_DESCONTO,dados.DESCONTO, dados.INICIO_DESCONTO, dados.FIM_DESCONTO,  dados.CATEGORIA_1);
  sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}   
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\\Teste\\teste.txt", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.